# Очередная загадка IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Как же мне надоело уже разгадывать эти бесконечные ребусы верстки для тупейшего браузера всех времен и народов Internet Exlorera! Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, почему в IE на [этой странице](http://www.spravka-azov.ru/test/usefuls/histor-econ/history.php) вверху есть ссылочка "Разделы справочника", там в стилях стоит background-color с определенным цветом, а на странице выдает прозрачный фон, при чем если убрать градиенты, то все нормально, а с ними такая история, почему? Самое тупое, что на других страницах с аналогичной версткой все нормально!..

Comment: попробовал в IE (правда 10), работает также, как и в других броузера.

Comment: Конечно вряд ли, но попробуйте использовать не background-color, a просто background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте для осла прописать следующее (*в CSS строка 1326*):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F5EBFA', endColorstr='#D3B8E0');
```

Comment: Дело в том, что мне не нужен этот градиент, ладно уже, пусть хотя бы бекграунд заданный отображает, ведь на других страницах с абсолютно аналогичной версткой все нормально, а здесь-то что?!

Comment: Отличное решение, спасибо! При чем, сразу нескольких проблем, я-то думал, что универсальных решений для эксплорера по градиентам нет, а оказалось есть!

Comment: Денис, как с вами по личке связаться, есть предложение.

Comment: Одно важное дополнение. Чтобы это свойство работало и на 8-м, нужно продублировать эту же строку и поставить в ее начало -ms-filter:, а после двоеточия все взять в кавычки. Универсальное решение будет выглядеть так
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorstr='#F5EBFA', endColorstr='#D3B8E0')";
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F5EBFA', endColorstr='#D3B8E0');
При чем, все это должно стоять в самом начале свойств из-за особенностей 8-го.Нашел в интернете http://www.xiper.net/manuals/css-extensions/internet-explorer/filters/gradient.htm

Comment: В чем состоит предложение?

Answer (score 2):

Уже раз третий отвечаю на подобные вопросы с одним маленьким скриптом:

```
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') ){
  //Шлем ишака на скачивание нормального браузера
  header("Location: http://www.google.com/intl/ru/chrome/browser/");
}
```

Comment: а мне нравится твой ответ!

Comment: @Shrek, Везде один позитив :)

Comment: Ответ нужно номинировать на лучший ответ года XD) Плюсую!

Comment: не думаю, что стоит так радикально, да еще и только на хром...
Начать с того, что это не решение проблемы, описанной в вопросе. Это обходной путь, может, и не самый плохой. Однако учтите множество мест, в которых идиоты-админы-параноики: IE не заменили, а устанавливать что-либо запретили. Таким людям вход на сайт будет закрыт.

Скорее стоит редиректить на страницу, сверстанную с минимумом стилей и скриптов. А предложение скачать выводить рядом с картинкой как будет лучше, если пользователь поставит браузер, не лишая его возможности получить инфу.
Вам скажут спасибо.

Comment: Ну, хм. Так можно сделать на личном хомяке, но если вы пошлёте за хорошим браузером потенциального покупателя, ваш менеджмент не будет в восторге.

Comment: Не могу пройти мимо и присоединится к коментарием. Только вот, @knes, я думаю всё же, что это даже на "не самый плохой" вариант не тянет. Вариант отвратительный, т.к. лишает юзера право на выбор. А иногда, как правильно вы заметили по поводу админов, это его обрекает на безысходность.

Comment: на "не самый плохой" вариант не тянет// Бывает гораздо хуже. Ту-то хоть можно с отключенным JS прорваться на окривевший сайт. Можно делать редирект на уровне сервера с блокировкой контента.   
Еще почему не самый плохой - при всей моей нелюбви к хрому, я признаю, что это один из самых качественных продуктов, если не самый(холивар, привет). Можно редиректить на любой другой браузер, который нравится автору. Какой-нибудь Maxthon...

Comment: > Можно редиректить на любой другой браузер

Тогда надо внести некоторые изменения в суперглобальный массив $_SERVER - **$_SERVER['USER_PREFERENCES_BROWSER']** )) Можно будет узнавать предпочтения пользователя и редиректить на сачивание соответствующего браузера ;)

Comment: Я бы еще Билу Гейтсу руки бы пооборвал, но как ваше так и мое решение далеко от реальности, увы. К сожалению, бОльшая часть пользователей справочников это дамы и какая-нибудь блондинко будет сторонится такой ссылки как чумы ("вот скачаю, а вдруг все сломается").

Comment: ути-пути, как мило - ишака в очередной раз пнули. Только вот практической ценности в ответе вовсе никакой нет

Comment: @DreamChild, *lol*

Answer (score 0):

Тут может быть z-Index виноватым. Ишак очень этим достаёт. Иногда тупым сдвигом DIV ниже в HTML можно решить проблему получасовой головоной боли CSS/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Тут можно сделать кроссбраузерный градиент, все подробно описано как, работает даже в ие7